# Safari move td's to new row on mobile

Tags: css, safari, webkit, mobile-safari

I have this old website that needs to kinda work on mobile. The whole thing is built on tables. On mobile I need the columns to take up 100% of the screens width and essentially go on a new line. In chrome, IE, FireFox.. it just works. However on IOS and Safari it will not go on a new line and the rest of the columns just crunch into the corner (looks real bad)

CSS I have tried: `td { display: block; width:100%; float: left; }`

Anyone know why on safari only it will not go on a new line?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stuck with this issue. Safari will override table styles (without notice) unless you add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of the file

Comment: Using a DOCTYPE declaration is basic best practice. Always be sure to use it.